# How to enable `geom_text` to recognize `aes` in QPLOT (R programming)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a data that looks like [this](http://dpaste.com/1271039/plain/)

```
ensg mirna_hgc time value perc id
ENSG00000211521 MIR665 x 89 2.07612456747405 1
ENSG00000207787 MIR98 x 73 1.73010380622837 2
...
ENSG00000207827 MIR30A y 99 21.4532871972318 288
ENSG00000207757 MIR93 y 94 1.73010380622837 289
```

What I'm trying to do is to create a facet plot with label on top of it.
The label can be easily called from the `perc` column.

Using this code:

```
dat.m <- read.delim("http://dpaste.com/1271039/plain/",header=TRUE,sep=" ")

qplot(value, data=dat.m,facets=time~.,binwidth=1,main="")+
xlab("Value")+ ylab("Count")+
theme(legend.position="none")+
stat_bin(aes(value,label=sprintf("%.01f",perc)),geom="text")
```

But it gave me this error:

```
Error: geom_text requires the following missing aesthetics: label
```

What I'm trying to do is to generate this plot:
    [image]

Comment: I'll say I've found `qplot` syntax just makes `ggplot2` more confusing for me. I can't quite find the solution to your problem using `ggplot()` syntax, but I advice you to try that approach - it is much easier to understand when plots start to get complicated.

Comment: How this can work , if your perc variable does not corresponds corresponds to your bins? Maybe you should bin it manually and assign it without aes.

Comment: Each `value` (within `time` category ) has one-to-one correspondence with `perc`. For example `time=x,value=100` always have `perc=7.6`

Comment: You've set your binwidth = 2, which means that each column will correspond (possibly) to two values and thus two values of perc.

Comment: @mnel thanks. even I changed to `binwidth=1` it gave the same error.

Comment: @neversaint -- I've posted an answer that will address your issues!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue arises in part

- because you are using `qplot` (which makes things more confusing than you need).
- You have set `binwidth =  2` which means each histogram bar is based (possibly) on 2 values of value. Your 1-to-1 mapping of perc to value is now 2 -to -1 mapping of perc to the binned values

Using `plyr` to continue the hadleyesque implementation we can aggregated before we plot

```
library(plyr)
agg.data <-  ddply(dat.m, .(value,time), summarize, p = unique(perc), n = length(perc))

ggplot(agg.data, aes(x= value)) + 
 geom_bar(aes(y = n),stat='identity') + 
 facet_grid(time~.) + 
 geom_text(aes(y=n, label = sprintf('%.01f',p)),vjust=-1,size=3)
```

[image]

If you want to use `geom_histogram` and display the proportions associated with each bar, this can be done quite easily, but you will need to use the values created by `stat_bin` (namely `..density..`, which is proportion allocated to each bar)

```
ggplot(dat.m, aes(x= value)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=2) +  
  facet_grid(time~.) + 
  stat_bin(aes(y = ..count.., label = sprintf('%.01f', 100 * ..density..)),
           binwidth=2,geom='text',vjust = -1)
```

[image]

and to replace the `0.0` with no labels use `ifelse` (with some definition trickery to avoid replicating the test.

```
ggplot(dat.m, aes(x= value)) + 
   geom_histogram(binwidth=2) +  facet_grid(time~.) + 
   stat_bin(aes(y = ..count.., 
     label = ifelse(test = (xxx <- sprintf('%.01f', 100 * ..density..))=='0.0','',xxx)),
     binwidth=2,geom='text',vjust = -0.7)
```

[image]

And note that you could get the same thing using `qplot` using

```
qplot(value, data=dat.m,facets=time~.,binwidth=2,main="")+
     xlab("Value")+ ylab("Count")+
     theme(legend.position="none")+
     stat_bin(aes(value,label=ifelse(test = (xxx <-  
       sprintf("%.01f",..density..*100))=='0.0','',xxx)),geom="text",binwidth=2,vjust = -0.7)
```

Comment: you save my life! Thanks. Is there a way I can change the 'size' independent of "binning"?